# Visual Studio 2013 hangs on create typescript file for large .cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm-2011, typescript, web-essentials

Using the C# .cs files conversion utility provided by Web Essentials, the latest nightly build as of today (thanks a ton for that) along with Visual Studio 2013 to generate a typescript file from CRM 2011 EntityGeneratedCode which is a large ~10Mb .cs file. My visual studio hangs and empty .d.ts files are generated. Anyone knows a fix for the issue?

Comment: You probably should post your issue here: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues. Have you watched task manager to see if VS memory utilization goes way up, and then dies?

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie, yes the VS memory utilization is increasing linearly to several 100mbs. Couldn't reach the point till it dies. will add it to issues.